# How to pass DLL of upstream project to downstream project in jenkin pipeline

Tags: asp.net-core, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Having the Jenkin pipeline where Proj A is an upstream project and Proj B is a downstream project. Have dependency between them, both are the independent solutions.

Currently, when 'project A' builds successfully it triggers 'Project B'. But I want to copy the latest dll from 'project A' to 'project B'. How could I manage such dependencies, I appreciate your early response?

**Proj A.sln (having A.dll)--> Proj B.sln ( should reference the New A.dll)**

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, without leaving Jenkins, is to have your Job A declare the .dll as "artifact" and archive it. Job B can then look up the list of its triggers, find the Job A build that triggered it, and look in its artifacts for the needed .dll.

Another way would be to store the .dll somewhere else, and trigger the downstream job with a parameter describing where to find it. You may use anything you're familiar with for this, beginning with FTP, shared drive, dump in a database, and up to a dedicated Artifactory server.

Comment: Thank you MaratC, appreciate your response. By any chance can you provide any link or example if possible?